# Doc and image file not opening in android

Tags: android, image, android-intent, doc

I am trying to open files using intent action but i can't for pdf and image files

**For image** all application going to crash (including gallery app)

**For doc/docx** i am using office suite but gives runtime exception from package (java.lang.RuntimeException). Please see code below :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase("jpg")
                    | extension.equalsIgnoreCase("jpeg")
                    | extension.equalsIgnoreCase("png")
                    | extension.equalsIgnoreCase("bitmap")) {
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(fileName), "image/*");
            } else if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase("xml")
                    | extension.equalsIgnoreCase("txt")
                    | extension.equalsIgnoreCase("csv")) {
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(fileName), "text/*");
            } else if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase("mp4")
                    | extension.equalsIgnoreCase("3gp")) {
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(fileName), "video/*");
            } else if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase("pdf")) {
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(fileName), "application/pdf");

                System.out.println("Pdf file to open "+fileName);

            } else if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase("doc")
                    | extension.equalsIgnoreCase("docx")) {

                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(fileName), "application/word");

            }


            context.startActivity(intent);
```

But if i tried to open those file by going file explorer both file opening correctly.

Comment: Can you post your exceptions / logcat?

Comment: when i tried to open for doc/docx file with office suite Office suite gives message missing <br> can any one knows how to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        //intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase("jpg")
                | extension.equalsIgnoreCase("jpeg")
                | extension.equalsIgnoreCase("png")
                | extension.equalsIgnoreCase("bitmap")) {
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://"+fileName), "image/*");
        } else if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase("xml")
                | extension.equalsIgnoreCase("txt")
                | extension.equalsIgnoreCase("csv")) {
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://"+fileName), "text/*");
        } else if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase("mp4")
                | extension.equalsIgnoreCase("3gp")) {
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://"+fileName), "video/*");
        }else if(extension.equalsIgnoreCase("pdf")){
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://"+fileName), "application/pdf");
        }else if( extension.equalsIgnoreCase("doc")
                | extension.equalsIgnoreCase("docx")){
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://"+fileName), "text/*");
        }
        // else
        // if(extension.equalsIgnoreCase("mp3")|extension.equalsIgnoreCase("amr")|extension.equalsIgnoreCase("wav")){
        // intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(fileName), "audio/mp3");
        // }
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its issue of the file uri class not returning file 
I found the error

It was Uri.parse(fileName)

I used now **Uri.fromFile(fileName)** its working now.